# Upload file using WCF REST

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, file-upload

I am using following code :

```
    static void test()
        {
            string address = "http://localhost:4700/HostDevServer/HelloWorldService.svc";
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(address);
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
            Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            string fileContents = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
            byte[] bodyContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileContents);
            reqStream.Write(bodyContents, 0, bodyContents.Length);
            reqStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse resp;
            try
            {
                **resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();**
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                resp = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", resp.ProtocolVersion, (int)resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription); 
        }



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace MyWCFServices
{
    public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
    {
        public String GetMessage(String name)
        {
            return "Hello world from " + name + "!";
        }

        public bool UploadFile(Stream fileContent)
        {
            using (StreamReader fileContentReader = new StreamReader(fileContent))
            {
                string content = fileContentReader.ReadToEnd();
                File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(@"c:\temp\aa.tmp"), content);
            }
            return false;
        }  
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

namespace MyWCFServices
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IHelloWorldService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        String GetMessage(String name);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "File/{fileName}")]
        //[WebContentType("application/octet-stream")]
        bool UploadFile(Stream fileContents); 

        //[OperationContract]
        //[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile/{fileName}")]
        //void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContent); 
    }
}
```

While uploading file, i get an error of Unsopported media type at the code highlighted in bold. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't directly see why it would affect this particular example - you shouldn't write the bytes of a file to a web request, because of the potential presence of byte values that are not expected or supported.

You should probably encode the bytes of the file as base 64 using

```
Convert.ToBase64String
```

Effectively uploading the file as a string.

At the other end you then treat the value as a string parameter on your service method, and use

```
Convert.FromBase64String
```

To get the bytes, and then you have the original file again.  At my company we have web services that we use to take binary files such as `docx` and this is how we do it - it works a treat.